# Automatically pass values to insert

Tags: javascript

I have an array which is stored on `columnNum` and has the follownig values `Price, Location, Year, Name` and the same values are used on the insert. I need a way to go automatically insert the following values on the insert without writing them down.

```js
let columnNum = Object.keys(record.fields);

const { data, error } = await supabase
.from('airtableRecords')
.insert([
{ userID: '123', Sample1: record.fields.Price, Sample2: record.fields.Location, Sample3: record.fields.Year, Sample4: record.fields.Name },
])
if (error) console.log('error', error)
```

Comment: But isn't the keys and the values already in an object (record.fields)? So, except from the userID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to build your insert object

```js
columnNum.reduce((result, columnNum) => {
  result[columnNum] = record.fields[columnNum];
  return result;
}, {userID: '123'})
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can guess the data `record.fields` looks more or less like this:

```
{Price: 100, Location: "here", Year: 2021, Name: "John"}
```

So the object (or array) that you parse into the function `insert` is just that data and then the userID. Would this solve your issue:

```
let dataToInsert = record.fields;
dataToInsert.userID = '123';

const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('airtableRecords')
  .insert([dataToInsert])
if (error) console.log('error', error)
```